# Difference between list[1:3] and list[1,2,3] ? why indexing list[1:3] throws an errror in the list given in descripction

Tags: r, list, subset

Here is a list `x <-  list(a = list(1:5) , b = c(6:10) )` . when sub setting 
`x[[c(2,3)]] works  but x[[1,3]])` throws an error subscript out of bounds . But When `a = list(10,12,13)` . It works .

why ?

what is the difference between `list[1:3]` and `list[1,2,3]`
why sub setting `list[1:3]` throws an error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list[1:3]` says to construct a list from the first 3 elements of the original list.  It's different from `list[[1:3]]`, which says to take the 3rd element of the 2nd element of the first element of the list.

`list[1,2,3]` is completely different.  It needs `list` to be a 3 way array, e.g.

```
x <- array(1:12, c(2,2,3))
```

where `x` will print as

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   11
[2,]   10   12
```

and `x[1,2,3]` would be `11`.

As @joran said, read `?Extract` for more details.